# go global variable not reflecting the correct value

Tags: go

I have the following code

```
package main

import ( 
    "fmt"
    "flag"
)

var outputOnly bool


func something() string {
    if outputOnly {
        fmt.Println("outputting only")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("executing commands")
    }   
    return "blah"
}

func main() {

    vmoutputonlyPtr     := flag.Bool("outputonly",false,"If set it will only output the commands it would execute, naturally without the correct parameter values set.")
    flag.Parse()
    outputOnly          := *vmoutputonlyPtr 
    if outputOnly {
        fmt.Println("outputonly commands will not execute")
    }

    var blah string
    blah = something()
    fmt.Println("blah is " + blah)
}
```

But the output is this:

```
$ ./se -outputonly                       
outputonly commands will not execute
executing commands
```

ie. it appears that the function something() is aware of the global variable, but does not reflect its true value. This is my first attempt at golang. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You used `:=`, so it's a local variable that shadows the global one. Use `=` for assignment to existing variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line in `main`.

```
outputOnly := *vmoutputonlyPtr
```

`:=` ***declares a new variable*** on the left, `outputOnly`, of the type of the expression on the right, `*vmoutputonlyPtr` and assigns the expression to it. It's equivalent to...

```
var outputOnly bool = *vmoutputonlyPtr
```

This new `outputOnly` ["shadows"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your global `outputOnly` in its scope. So all the code after `outputOnly := *vmoutputonlyPtr` in `main` refers to this `outputOnly` local to `main`. While `something()` refers to the global `outputOnly`.

[See *Redeclaration and Reassignment* in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#redeclaration) for more about variable shadowing in Go.

If you want to assign to an existing variable, just use `=`.

```
outputOnly = *vmoutputonlyPtr
```